# How to sort JSON output from AWS CLI using JMESPath

Tags: sorting, aws-cli, jmespath

I try to sort this output from AWS CLI by `ImageId`, and I executed command below.

`aws ec2 describe-images --profile xxxxxxxxxx \
--filter Name=tag:Name,Values=Backup*some-string* \
--query "Images[*].[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]|[0],ImageId]"`

output is:

```
[
    [
        "Backup-20191215T174530Z-utc-some-string",
        "ami-004"
    ],
    [
        "Backup-20191219T174631Z-utc-some-string",
        "ami-002"
    ],
    [
        "Backup-20191208T174534Z-utc-some-string",
        "ami-001"
    ],
    [
        "Backup-20191222T174530Z-utc-some-string",
        "ami-003"
    ],
    [
        "Backup-20191221T174530Z-utc-some-string",
        "ami-005"
    ]
]
```

I found `sort_by` functions of JMESPath could be a solution but that is too hard to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-images --profile xxxxxxxxxx \
--filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=Backup*some-string*" \
--query "sort_by(Images[*].[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]|[0],ImageId], &[0])"
```

or

```
aws ec2 describe-images --profile xxxxxxxxxx \
--filter "Name=tag:Name,Values=Backup*some-string*" \
--query "Images[*].[Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]|[0],ImageId] | sort_by(@, &[0])"
```

is working fine for me. `&` (expression type operator) is needed.

Comment: Just FYI, you are missing a closing parens in the first example/answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is, In my solution below, I am sorting the output first by the `ImageId` and then applying the projections.

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filter Name=tag:Environment,Values=Staging --output json --query "(sort_by(Images[], &ImageId))[*].[ImageId, Tags[?Key=='Environment'].Value | [0]]"
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it returns an error `In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: ['Backup-20191215T174530Z-xxxxxxxxxx', 'ami-abcdefghijklmn'], expected one of: ['string', 'number'], received: "null"`

Comment: additional `[]` also returns the same type of error. And what I want to achieve is just sort the output by the name of the tag value.

Comment: i am in a road trip, just came up with this, have a try, otherwise i will try something soon

Comment: got it working, apply your tag names and see if it working.

Comment: I found a solution for this, so added my answer. Thank you for helping me.